# How to open pdf file which is located at server side by specifying its server side path in android using mupdf

Tags: android, mupdf

I am using mupdf library to render pdf file within my android application.
When I am specifying local path for pdf, it open successfully within my app, where as when I write following code to render server side pdf file, it gives error message in dialog box as can not open pdf file

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf");  
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MuPDFActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

I am new in android application development.

Here is my LogCat:

```
06-03 10:57:53.517    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-03 10:57:56.676    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-03 10:57:56.717    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb4a93ec0, tid 1645
06-03 10:57:56.873    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-03 10:57:57.380    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample I/System.out﹕ Trying to open /wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf
06-03 10:57:57.419    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample W/linker﹕ libmupdf.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
06-03 10:57:57.503    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample E/libmupdf﹕ Opening document...
06-03 10:57:57.504    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample E/libmupdf﹕ error: cannot open /wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf
06-03 10:57:57.504    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample E/libmupdf﹕ error: cannot load document '/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf'
06-03 10:57:57.505    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample E/libmupdf﹕ error: Cannot open document: '/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf'
06-03 10:57:57.505    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample E/libmupdf﹕ Failed: Cannot open document: '/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf'
06-03 10:57:57.508    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample I/System.out﹕ java.lang.Exception: Cannot open file: /wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf
06-03 10:57:57.853    1645-1657/com.tekinarslan.sample I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2315(157KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 887KB/1117KB, paused 997us total 139.942ms
06-03 10:57:58.297    1645-1657/com.tekinarslan.sample I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 358(28KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(81KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 985KB/2009KB, paused 14.274ms total 208.324ms
06-03 10:57:58.482    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-03 10:57:58.601    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb4b36ff0, tid 1665
06-03 10:57:58.613    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-03 10:57:58.640    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-03 10:57:58.655    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-03 10:57:58.655    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb4b5a240, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-03 10:57:58.795    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-03 10:57:58.795    1645-1665/com.tekinarslan.sample W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb4b5a260, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-03 10:57:59.114    1645-1645/com.tekinarslan.sample I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Can you add error log?

Comment: I have updated my question with LogCat details. thanks.

Comment: Is same file opening from local storage? Can you try it?

Comment: yes,I have tried, but for another file, when I store abc.pdf in assets folder and specify that path, it get opened successfully

Comment: can you try with same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android demo app, unlike thw Windows demo app, has no built-in HTTP client. So you cannot simply provide a URL.

If you want to do this you will have to implement the HTTP communication yourself. I believe that the Windows application uses the Curl library, I have no idea if this is available for Android.